# Plotting the components of a vector-valued function: Legend

Tags: plotting, legending

Suppose I have a vector-valued function $f(x)$, and want to plot each component with respect to $x$.

If I try, as stated in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html),

```
Foo[inp_] := {Sin[inp], Cos[inp], Tan[inp]}
Plot[Foo[n], {n, 0, Pi/2}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

I get a single-coloured plot without any legend. How can I add a legend saying which curve is which component? (I have tried PlotLegends-> "Expressions", which also didn't work)

The output currently looks like this:
[image: Output of command]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap `Foo[n]` in `Evaluate`:

```
Foo[inp_] := {Sin[inp], Cos[inp], Tan[inp]};
Plot[Evaluate@Foo[n], {n, 0, Pi/2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]